# How to set background colour for a button in selected and pressed states that has @drawable image

Tags: android, button

[image: buttons screen shot]

In the image above you can see the first Home button is in a pressed state. It has no background colour and I need it to to be black (preferably shaded similar to the default color shown for the other buttons at the same time as keeping the image). I also need to change the text color to white.

I have XML code that changes the image depending on state but I'm at a total loss as to how to change the background colour at the same time.

The code I have for this particular button is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_about_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_about_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_about_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_about_unpressed" /><!-- default/unchecked -->
</selector>
```

and:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MnuBtnStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">1dip</item> 
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">1dip</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

How I can achieve this?

**UPDATE**

My requirements for the button are:

1. I must be able to change the image for different states
2. I must be able to change the text using strings or in code not bothered which
3. I must be able to set the button face colour for default and differing states.

Am I going to need to create a new custom control to achieve this?
If so, what would be my best approach, bearing in mind that this is my first Android project?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ImageButton instead of Button:

```
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="60dip"
android:layout_height="60dip"
android:src="@drawable/state_btn_icon"
android:background="@drawable/state_btn_background"/>
```

state_btn_icon.xml defines different states for the icon of the button

and

state_btn_background defines different states for the background

Comment: Thanks for the reply but image button is no good as I have to fill the parent width therefore stretching the button width or reducing the width to fill the top of the screen depending on the quantity of buttons. There will be more on some screens and less on others. Any other ideas?

Comment: You can use android:adjustViewBounds="true" so the image will not streach

Comment: Ok, but can I add text to an image button? I have to be able to change the wording on the button without having to redo images for each screen resolution. If this is not possible to do perhaps I should make my own custom button?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that the button should have a text. That way you should think about creating a custom view